# How to combine two JavaScript in one in order to use if condition?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have below JavaScript which can resize iframe in html

```
 function resizeIframe(iframe) {
                        iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
                        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => resizeIframe(iframe));
                        }
```

it works fine,

And I have another javascript which can be used in if to check data

```
function session_checking()
                {
                    $.post( "resize_iframe.php", function( data ) {
                       
                        if(data == "1")
                        {
                            alert("condition is true");                
                        }
                        
                        else
                        {
                            alert("condition is false");   
                        }

                    });
                }
                var validateSession = setInterval(session_checking, 1000);
```

And above JavaScript works fine.

I need to combine the above JavaScript like below but it does not work

```
<script>
            function session_checking()
            {
                $.post( "resize_iframe.php", function( data ) {
                
                    if(data == "1")
                    {  
                        function resizeIframe(iframe) {
                        iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
                        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => resizeIframe(iframe));
                        }
                    }
                    
                    else
                    {
                     function resizeIframe(iframe) {
                     iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight - "px";
                     window.requestAnimationFrame(() => resizeIframe(iframe));
                    }
                });
            }
            var validateSession = setInterval(session_checking, 1000);
</script>
```

html

```
<iframe src="order.php" width="100%" onload="setInterval(resizeIframe(this),1000);" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Please anyone can help me
Thank you

Comment: You don't need to put the function into `session_checking()` you just invoke your function using `resizeIframe(iframe);`. I'd suggest you read up on [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: Just a head up, `var validateSession = setInterval(session_checking, 1000);`   If you plan on scaling this to lots of users, that is going to be a bit of a resource hog.  Your basically doing a full HTTP Request for something that returns a 1 or a 0 every second.

Comment: Replace `alert("condition is true"); ` (and the other alert) with `resizeIframe(iframe);`  **edit** I see one is `+px` and the other is `-px` *but this looks like a typo*

Comment: Yes when condition is true I have to apply +px when condition is false I have to apply -px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `function resizeIframe(iframe)` you are simply *defining* a function. It's not called, so it doesn't execute.

```
function session_checking(iframe) {
    $.post( "resize_iframe.php", function( data ) {
        if(data == "1"){  
            iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
        } else {
            iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight - "px";
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => resizeIframe(iframe));
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". Just saying that [is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, I forgot to add (iframe) in the function that's why I replied that. But now it works fine. Thank you